# socket.ssl in Python3

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, ssl

I am trying to make a library work originally designed for Python2.x in Python3. There is a call to a library called 'socket.ssl'. 'Socket' is avalable for both Python 3 and 2 however the .ssl seems to be only avalble for 'python2.x'. I have tried to look at alternatives but couldn't find any material on this. Does anyone know of an alternative/replacement for this 'socket.ssl'?

Thanks

```
try:
    import socket
    socket.ssl
except:
    print("needs SSL support")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html - If this is not enough please ask a more specific question which includes what you are trying to achieve and how you did it before.

Comment: try:
    import socket
    socket.ssl
except:
    print("needs SSL support") sys.exit(1)

Comment: the above is what I cannot import when using python 3. I cannot figure out what the equivalent woud be for python3 -- this 'docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html' doesnt help. sorry

Comment: How about a simple "import ssl" ?